# Ordering by an expression in a partition by

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, common-table-expression

I have some almost duplicate data in my database (duplicates based on these 5 columns: `Date`, `Code`, `Expiry`, `TheType`, `Strike`, there are many more columns but they won't be counted towards labeling a record a duplicate). I want to keep only one record in each case and the one I want to keep is the one whose `mtm` column is closest to its `checkprice` column (i.e. minimize `abs(mtm-checkprice)`). So I think the CTE below gets pretty close if I can just order the partition by that expression. The way I tried gives me the error `Invalid column name 'diff'.`

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT *, ABS(Mtm - checkprice) as diff, 
          RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Date, Strike, Mtm, /* ALL THE OTHER COLUMN NAMES */ 
                                ORDER BY diff DESC)
   FROM FullStats
)
--DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1    
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
ORDER BY Date, Code, Expiry, TheType, Strike
```

Any ideas on how to rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ABS(mtm-checkprice)` in the `ORDER BY` of the `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT *, Diff = ABS(mtm-checkprice),
      RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Date, Code, Expiry, TheType, Strike
                            ORDER BY ABS(mtm-checkprice) ASC)
   FROM FullStats
)
--DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1    
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
ORDER BY Date, Code, Expiry, TheType, Strike
```

You cannot access `Diff` in the `ROW_NUMBER`, only outside of the CTE.

Comment: Thanks, obviously I should have tried that before posting. I also took the liberty of fixing two other dumb errors I had made in the question in your answer just in case it help someone else. I should have partitioned over only the columns I was searching for duplicates over and it should be sorted ascending since I want it to return the values to delete not the ones to keep.